# How to associate multiple BigQuery array fields?

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery, unnest

I am working with a BigQuery data table that is using multiple array fields to store elements of the same logical record.

In this case there is one array field for ‘product code’, a second array field for ‘quantity’ and a third array field for ‘price’. All array fields will have great same number if elements.

How can I build a BigQuery query that extracts the product code, quantity and price as a three column result set?

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, rec.*
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(ARRAY(    
  SELECT AS STRUCT code, quantity, price
    FROM UNNEST(code) code WITH OFFSET
    JOIN UNNEST(quantity) quantity WITH OFFSET USING(OFFSET)
    JOIN UNNEST(price) price WITH OFFSET USING(OFFSET)  
)) rec
```

You can test, play with above using sample dummy data as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, ['product1', 'product2', 'product3'] code, [10, 20, 30] quantity, [2.99, 1.99, 0.99] price UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, ['product4', 'product5', 'product6'], [60, 50, 40], [3.99, 4.99, 5.99] 
)
SELECT id, rec.*
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(ARRAY(    
  SELECT AS STRUCT code, quantity, price
    FROM UNNEST(code) code WITH OFFSET
    JOIN UNNEST(quantity) quantity WITH OFFSET USING(OFFSET)
    JOIN UNNEST(price) price WITH OFFSET USING(OFFSET)  
)) rec
```

with output

```
Row id  code        quantity    price    
1   1   product1    10          2.99     
2   1   product2    20          1.99     
3   1   product3    30          0.99     
4   2   product4    60          3.99     
5   2   product5    50          4.99     
6   2   product6    40          5.99
```